# RoR: Devise Customize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to follow this tutorial about adding a username field to Devise: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

However, when I edit the view files `new.html.erb` I don't see any changes take place when I refresh the signup/login page...

What would be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do:

```
rails g devise:views
```

or

```
rails g devise:views MyModel
```

When using only only model, you need to use the former version to generate the correct views. Or rename your app/views/my_models to app/views/devise

Comment: rails g devise:views creates files in app/views/devise
rails g devise:views users creates files in app/views/users

Comment: Right. That was a dumb question.  I'm fooling around with both commands and renaming folders.  Nothing is picking up yet...is that weird? It's still just the default sign_in and sign_up form.

Comment: Did you restart your server just in case? I was going through this this morning to make some notes and had exactly the same problem. Whe n using just one model for authentication, you need to edit the app/views/devise/.... views.

Comment: This is weird.  I just added `:3000` to the serving ip and it worked.  Maybe I need to change rails server to port 80?

Comment: I think you're right.  I'll try this when I'm home with the domain name...I have to use the IP when I'm at work due to proxy... Thanks for the help!